# Is Paypal Payments Pro compatible with Paypal's Adaptive Payments API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using Paypal's [Adaptive Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) to process parallel payments from one sender/buyer to two receivers. For example, a sender/buyer buys a digital good for $10, and using the Adaptive Payments API, $7 is sent to receiver A and $3 is sent to receiver B.

I'm interested in using [Paypal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/website-payments-pro) to design and host the checkout page, instead of kicking the sender/buyer over to Paypal.com. Does anyone know whether Paypal Payments Pro is compatible with the Adaptive Payments API, and whether there are any restrictions on use of the API through Payments Pro? Paypal's documentation isn't very clear on this.

Comment: how did you solve this problem I'm facing the same, did you could build your own shopping cart and then make this kind of payments? or do you have to use the Adaptive Payment Solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I have contacted PayPal Merchant Technical Services because I was thinking of using paypal payment pro in our site. However, I also need to use CHAINED payment which is a type of Adaptive Payment.

According to them, Paypal Payments Pro won't work with Adaptive because they are different types of integration. They have suggested to use Embedded flow which lets the customer to login using a lightbox or a minibrowser; thus, not requiring your customer to leave your site.

For more information about this kind of integration, please have a look here:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf#page=25

I don't know if I have answered your question, but i hope in some way, it helped you.

Comment: Damn, so basically you can't make split payment with the Payment Pro API? how do you make a solution using this? ...

Comment: @ncubica did you a find a solution to this? I'm looking to do the same as well

Comment: To be honest I don't remember has been long time ago, maybe I ended changing or adapting the payment flow, but now exist easier and better API for payment take a look into https://stripe.com/ca maybe? Also I don't know if paypal has come with a better solution.

Comment: @ncubica the problem with Stripe is that they don't offer chained payments where multiple recipients can get paid